# Best approach for iOS social integration

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I have recently faced up to integrate social networks with iOS.

In the past, I have done so many things that deal with social networking integration and I thought, it was quite easy thing for me.

But had no chance to work with it more than a year and now I was trying to do it and there are too much complex things which is related to this.

It was much different when I was doing in iOS 5 and `FacebookSDK` was upgraded too much.

Found that [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) have the most potential to be used but it seems like too heavy for simple integration.

Was liked to use Social.framework or iOS Facebook SDK and it also have confusion.

What happens if the social account registered in settings and Facebook app are different?

Seems like `UIActivityViewController` is the easiest way but seems like to have iOS specific version issues.

So I need any suggestions for experienced developers which is the best way to integrate social networking and do whatever I want.

I want to build a new module which do login, get basic info, and publish photo and videos

Comment: The answer all depends on how you gonna use the social networks in your app? Does user needs to use to login? Or your app needs to use some basic info of the user, (like profile pics, and friends list)? Or your app simply wants to enable users to share something via the social network? If you're not sure about the answers of these questions, then you should think about them before choose the right and easiest way to implement.

Comment: It depends on your use case. Here is a good doc explaining what all use cases Facebook SDK can help you solve: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios